# date and time on x axis in ios charts by Daniel Gindi

Tags: ios, date, time, ios-charts

how can i add both time and date on x axis in ios charts by Daniel Gindi?

Thanks in advance for the answers!

```
extension ChartXAxisFormatter: IAxisValueFormatter {

func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
    if let dateFormatter = dateFormatter {

        let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: value)
        return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    }
    return ""
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure your dateFormatter with a format string, and add times to that. From memory, something like:

```
dateFormatter.setDateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm"
```

Hope that helps!